# Rails will_paginate with named scope for associations > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, will-paginate

Similar to [will_paginate with named_scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792119/will-paginate-with-named-scopes) but not getting an error - rather unexpected results. Rails version 4.

If I have a scope in a `Foo` model (where a user `has_many: foos`) - `models/foo.rb`:

```
belongs_to :user
scope :hasCars, -> { joins(:cars) }
```

And now try use the scope with `will_paginate` (in the controller):

```
@foos = auser.foos.hasCars.paginate(:page=>1,:per_page=>20)
```

Then the view duplicates each `foo` by the number of `cars` they have in the `:through ownership` association - so for foo 1 - 4 of a given user:

```
foo1.cars.size # =>1
foo2.cars.size # =>4
foo3.cars.size # =>0
foo4.cars.size # =>2
```

View:

```
foo1
foo2
foo2
foo2
foo2
foo4
foo4
```

Works as expected without the paginate and paginate works fine without the scope.

The association of Foo to cars is `:through => :ownership`. I guess it's to do with the way the scope is created using a join and how that join is passed to `will_paginate`. This is the query I see in the logs:

`SELECT  "".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "ownership" ON "ownership"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" INNER JOIN "cars" ON "car"."id" = "ownership"."car_id" WHERE "foos"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]`

This should return the correct number of rows. But then for each car owned by Foo, I see a query `cars from cars where foo_id = X` being duplicated, am guessing from a query generated by `will_paginate`

Is there a better way to create the scope? Or should will_paginate be set up differently? Or could this be a will_paginate bug?

I have tried using `joins(:ownership)` too in the scope - same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

[Rails will_paginate shows duplicates on HABTM models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729816/rails-will-paginate-shows-duplicates-on-habtm-models)

```
auser.foos.hasCars.group("car_id").paginate...
```